# passing a json payload to thejavascript eval function

Tags: javascript, json, dom, xss

can someone inject on my website a payload in a json format passed to the eval javascript function and being executed .

for example :

```
eval(alert(4)); // we have an alert box showing the number 4

eval(({"alert(4)":"alert(4)"})) // can this lead to an xss
```

thank you

Comment: What is generating the input string? Is it coming from a textbox?

Comment: it's coming from the url .

Comment: So it's coming from a GET request that a user can manipulate?